# Angular 7: How to get list of objects with JSONP

Tags: angular, jsonp

I have a problem with jsonp. I want to write a function that returns a json data like that;

```
[{value:"data",id:"1"},{value:"data",id:"1"}]
```

i must use jsonp because otherwise i get CORS error (because im trying to get datas from another server).

data.service.ts;

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient,private jsonp:Jsonp) { }
dataUrl:string;

getJsonp(){
   this.dataUrl = ***LINK***;
   this.jsonp.get(this.dataUrl).pipe(
      map(res=> console.log(res))
   );
}
```

i tried to print the "res" for see what is return from server but its not print anything.
Could you please help he?

Answer (score 0):

may be is to late, but some user could needs tips.

Try to asigment the "res" to new parameter and return this..

```
    response: any[] = [];

getJsonp(){
   this.dataUrl = ***LINK***; //don't forget uses "callback=JSONP_CALLBACK"
   this.jsonp.get(this.dataUrl).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        this.response = res.results;
        console.log(this.response);
        return this.response;
      })
   );
}
```